# Numpy Array View and Garbage Collection

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
def f():
    x = np.arange(100)
    return x[:5]
```

f returns a y, which is a view on x.

Will x still be using memory in the background?

Answer (score 5):

If you return a view `x` won't be garbage collected. Moreover it will be still accessible through `base`.

```
>>> y = f()
>>> y.base
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, ...., 99])
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: yes. Whilst `x` will be kept alive by your slice. See the documentation for [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing).

You should copy the view before returning.

```
return x[:5].copy()
```